# Discrete Mathematics Notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty understanding the notation of discrete math.

```
Here (x | y) means “x evenly divides y” i.e. divides without a remainder.

∃S ⊆ Nat: (∀y ∈ S : (∀x ∈  Nat : (x | y ) ⇒ (x = y) ∨ (x = 1))))
```

Can someone explain this equation to me in english?

Answer (score 2):

There exists a subset $S$ of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ (or not containing $0$, depending on your definition) such that whenever $y \in S$ and $x$ is *any* natural number that's a divisor of $y$, then $x = 1$ or $x = y$.

That is, if you choose an element $y$ of $S$ and a divisor $x$ of $y$, then $x$ is either $1$ or $y$.

---

In particular, this implies that $S$ is a set consisting only of prime numbers or $1$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the help! What would the steps be to negate this phrase? Would it essentially be a set of all numbers that are not prime?

Comment: It would be a set of number containing at least one number with divisors that aren't just $1$ and the number.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a subset $S$ of the naturals such that for all elements $y$ in $S$ with the property that for all $x$ in the naturals with the property that $x$ evenly divides $y$ then $x$ is equal to $y$ or $x$ is equal to one.

Basically, You define a set $S$ in the naturals where every element in the subset has this property. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying there is a set of natural numbers `[∃S ⊆ Nat]` that has the property that for every number y in S `[∀y ∈ S]`, every divisor of x `[(x | y)]` is either y itself, or 1 `[(x = y) ∨ (x = 1)]`. You can probably guess that S is the set of prime numbers, and 1.

To get the composites, you can negate the inner phrase to get

∃S ⊆ Nat: (∀y ∈ S : (`~`∀x ∈  Nat : (x | y) ⇒ (x = y) ∨ (x = 1))))

which is equivalent by De Morgan's Law to

∃S ⊆ Nat: (∀y ∈ S : (`∃`x ∈  Nat : (x | y) `⇏` (x = y) ∨ (x = 1))))

which is in turn equivalent to

∃S ⊆ Nat: (∀y ∈ S : (∃x ∈  Nat : (x ≠ 1) ⋀ (x ≠ y) ⋀ (x | y))))

In English, this means there is a set where each member x has a divisor other than 1 or x, i.e the composites.